# ObjectDataSource fails to parse string to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, objectdatasource, datetime-format

I have a textbox with value that stores ValidFrom form value:

```
31.01.2012
```

and cultures set to:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

in web.config.

And now, ObjectDataSource update method:

```
    public static void UpdateLac(int id, DateTime ValidFrom)
    {
        /// ...
    }
```

fails as I get exception that string cannot be parsed. However date in format **dd.mm.yyyy** (**31.01.2012**) is valid en-GB format and can be parsed (as far as I know). I have tested it with following code:

```
            DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").DateTimeFormat;
            var date = DateTime.Parse("31.01.2012", dtfi);
            Console.Write(date.ToLongDateString());
```

So how come that ObjectDataSource internal conversion fails to convert **string** (31.01.2012) to **DateTime** in this example?

Comment: just try 01.31.2012  and see whether its working or not

Comment: 01.31.2012 gets converted to DateTime by ObjectDataSource, but 01.31.2012 is not converted when I call (just to test) DateTime.Parse("01.31.2012") inside postback (as my culture is set to en-GB)

Comment: Can object type is the ODS working with? If it is a custom type, can you provide the source code for it's properties and fields?

Comment: set format as dd.MM.yyyy hope its works

Comment: @Jeff : ObjectDataSource do not work with custom type. It calls UpdateMethod and passes .NET built in types (string, int, DateTime etc)

Comment: @satinder singh: thanks. but why should I change date format (and where)? Date format is not the issue, as it's parsed correctly throughout the web app unless ObjectDataSource tries to parse it.

Comment: @dragonfly That's not true. I have used it with custom types before.

Comment: @Jeff - "ObjectDataSource do not work with custom type" - I ment that in my example ObjectDataSource do not uses custom type, but .NET types :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the culture info is loaded directly from the OS ( in this case windows), you can check on your regional setting for the format specified. This is a screenshot from my pc:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/engbg.png/

As you can see the format for short date is: dd/MM/aa, so maybe there is something going on with your server regional settings or the input should be: 31/**01**/12 instead of 31.01.2012

Hope this helps.