# Which culture is used by ObjectDataSource to convert string to DateTime

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've just described my problem here: [ObjectDataSource fails to parse string to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294069/objectdatasource-fails-to-parse-string-to-datetime) . After a few google queries I came across this link: [ObjectDataSource – Cannot convert value of parameter value from System.String to System.DateTime](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/07/30/objectdatasource-cannot-convert-value-of-parameter-value-from-system-string-to-system-datetime/) , and short explanation:

> One bug I’ve come across a few times and again just recently is when using an ObjectDataSource with a GridView to update dates.  When doing the update the ObjectDataSource always uses the en-US culture and not the culture defined for the application.
>   The bug has been acknowledged by Microsoft but never fixed.

The workaround that involves manual parsing is ... unacceptable :) Do you know any other, more programmer friendly solution to that issue?

Comment: Have you tried some of the workarounds like _"manually specify the fields of data types subject to internationalization issues in the InsertParameters and/or UpdateParameters of the ObjectDataSource."_ ? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105016/objectdatasource-ignores-culture-information-when-updating For example: `<updateparameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="BirthDate" Type="DateTime" />
          </updateparameters>`

Answer (score 0):

Although this issue was apparently never fixed, there are several workarounds that you may use provided in [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105016/objectdatasource-ignores-culture-information-when-updating).  Not sure why parsing would be unacceptable.  It can be done in 1 line of code:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(myTextBox.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Observe that the culture is not hardcoded (which is the only reason I could think of that would make this unacceptable).

Comment: Thanks, by writing "unaccaptable" I was expressing my discontent with this bug, nothing else :)